# Failuer to import my break point file into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

last week,i add break-points for tracing the project,and then export the break-points to one file.But today i'm failuer to import my break point file into eclipse. Have anyone meet this problem before? or some suggestion?(Ps:I did change the project a little.)

Comment: Do you get an error message of some kind?

Comment: no response after I clicked "finish" button